# does python delete instances from swip in wrong order? Can it be modified?

Tags: python, c++, swig, smart-pointers

I used SWIG to wrap some classes in c++. My python script looks like

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import pyinput
import pygeom
import pystate
import pyeqfactory
import pyeigenprobfactory
import pyeigensolver

inp = pyinput.Input("heter1d/1d1g_heter")
geo = pygeom.ProbGeom1D(inp)
state = pystate.State1D(inp, geo);
equation = pyeqfactory.EqFactory1D.New(state)
eigenprob = pyeigenprobfactory.EigenProbFactory1D.New(state, equation)
solver = pyeigensolver.EigenSolver1D(state, eigenprob)
solver.solve_eigenproblem()
print state.get_keff()
```

and I got an error from a smart pointer class because an instance was being removed while still owned by other

```
--------------------------------------------------------
An error occurred in line <114> of file </home/segonpin/lib/dealii/source/base/subscriptor.cc> in function
    virtual dealii::Subscriptor::~Subscriptor()
The violated condition was: 
    counter == 0
The name and call sequence of the exception was:
    ExcInUse (counter, object_info->name(), infostring)
Additional Information: 
Object of class N6dealii13TriangulationILi1ELi1EEE is still used by 1 other objects.

(Additional information: <none>)

See the entry in the Frequently Asked Questions of deal.II (linked to from http://www.dealii.org/) for a lot more information on what this error means and how to fix programs in which it happens.

Stacktrace:
-----------
#0  /home/segonpin/lib/dealii-8.4.bin/lib/libdeal_II.g.so.8.4.2: dealii::Subscriptor::~Subscriptor()
#1  /home/segonpin/lib/dealii-8.4.bin/lib/libdeal_II.g.so.8.4.2: dealii::Triangulation<1, 1>::~Triangulation()
#2  /home/segonpin/codessebas/dealii-neutron-transport/python/_pygeom.so: Forest::ProbGeom<1>::~ProbGeom()
#3  /home/segonpin/codessebas/dealii-neutron-transport/python/_pygeom.so: 
#4  python: PyObject_Call
#5  python: PyObject_CallFunctionObjArgs
#6  /home/segonpin/codessebas/dealii-neutron-transport/python/_pygeom.so: 
#7  python: ) [0x4fd4e6]
#8  python: PyDict_SetItem
#9  python: _PyModule_Clear
#10  python: PyImport_Cleanup
#11  python: Py_Finalize
#12  python: Py_Main
#13  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: __libc_start_main
#14  python: _start
--------------------------------------------------------
```

The error disappear when I manually remove the two classes that generates the problem in the right order

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import pyinput
import pygeom
import pystate
import pyeqfactory
import pyeigenprobfactory
import pyeigensolver

inp = pyinput.Input("heter1d/1d1g_heter")
geo = pygeom.ProbGeom1D(inp)
state = pystate.State1D(inp, geo);
equation = pyeqfactory.EqFactory1D.New(state)
eigenprob = pyeigenprobfactory.EigenProbFactory1D.New(state, equation)
solver = pyeigensolver.EigenSolver1D(state, eigenprob)
solver.solve_eigenproblem()
print state.get_keff()

# these two lines solve the problem
del state
del geo
```

should not be python deleting these instances in the same order (because `geo` is used in the constructor of `state`)? Thanks!

---

Edit feb 15 2017, 11:19.

I can add some extra reasons about why I need to remove in a particular order. I am using swig to parse a c++ library (www.dealii.org), and when I create an instance of B that needs an instance of A to make sense, then a counter is increased in A saying that it is owned by B. This is used for deleting the objects (B needs A to exists, so we delete B before we delete A). If you do in other way you get an error. In this case the python instances contain some of these dependencies, so I must remove objects in a particular other to avoid the error message.

I have added some message to the python destructor

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import pyinput
import pygeom
import pystate
import pyeqfactory
import pyeigenprobfactory
import pyeigensolver

def deltalk(self):
  print type(self).__name__ ," die"

pyinput.Input.__del__ = deltalk
pygeom.ProbGeom1D.__del__ = deltalk
pystate.State1D.__del__ = deltalk
pyeqfactory.EqFactory1D.__del__ = deltalk
pyeigenprobfactory.EigenProbFactory1D.__del__ = deltalk
pyeigensolver.EigenSolver1D.__del__ = deltalk
pypostprocessing.PostProcessing1D.__del__ = deltalk

inp = pyinput.Input("heter1d/1d1g_heter")
geo = pygeom.ProbGeom1D(inp)
state = pystate.State1D(inp, geo);
equation = pyeqfactory.EqFactory1D.New(state)
eigenprob = pyeigenprobfactory.EigenProbFactory1D.New(state, equation)
solver = pyeigensolver.EigenSolver1D(state, eigenprob)
```

and when I run it I see that it is not destroying in the way that I need (destroying `geo` before `state` raise an error in the c++)

```
$ python test2_forest.py 
EigenSolver1D  die
ProbGeom1D  die

--------------------------------------------------------
An error occurred in line <114> of file </home/segonpin/lib/dealii/source/base/subscriptor.cc> in function
    virtual dealii::Subscriptor::~Subscriptor()
The violated condition was: 
    counter == 0
The name and call sequence of the exception was:
    ExcInUse (counter, object_info->name(), infostring)
Additional Information: 
Object of class N6dealii13TriangulationILi1ELi1EEE is still used by 1 other objects.

(Additional information: <none>)

See the entry in the Frequently Asked Questions of deal.II (linked to from http://www.dealii.org/) for a lot more information on what this error means and how to fix programs in which it happens.

Stacktrace:
-----------
#0  /home/segonpin/lib/dealii-8.4.bin/lib/libdeal_II.g.so.8.4.2: dealii::Subscriptor::~Subscriptor()
#1  /home/segonpin/lib/dealii-8.4.bin/lib/libdeal_II.g.so.8.4.2: dealii::Triangulation<1, 1>::~Triangulation()
#2  /home/segonpin/codessebas/dealii-neutron-transport/python/_pygeom.so: Forest::ProbGeom<1>::~ProbGeom()
#3  /home/segonpin/codessebas/dealii-neutron-transport/python/_pygeom.so: 
#4  python: PyObject_Call
#5  python: PyObject_CallFunctionObjArgs
#6  /home/segonpin/codessebas/dealii-neutron-transport/python/_pygeom.so: 
#7  python: ) [0x4fd4e6]
#8  python: PyDict_SetItem
#9  python: _PyModule_Clear
#10  python: PyImport_Cleanup
#11  python: Py_Finalize
#12  python: Py_Main
#13  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: __libc_start_main
#14  python: _start
```

Is there a general way of telling python to remove objects considering this dependence? or should I explicitly say it in the destructor of each class?

Thanks

Comment: Being used in the constructor does not mean anything... do you keep a reference to the other object?

Comment: Hi @Tali I am using swig to parse a c++ library (www.dealii.org), and when I create an instance of B that needs an instance of A to make sense, then a counter is increased in A saying that it is owned by B. This is used for deleting the objects (B needs A to exists, so we delete B before we delete A). If you do in other way you get an error. In this case the python instances contain some of these dependencies, so I must remove objects in a particular other to avoid the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone finds the same problem in the future, I have found a way to call the delete in the order that I want using `atexit`.

### Not clean but functional solution

It is not very clean, but I would be something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import pyinput
import pygeom
import pystate
import pyeqfactory
import pyeigenprobfactory
import pyeigensolver

def goodbye() :
  print "Goodbye!!\n"
import atexit
atexit.register(goodbye)

def deltalk(self):
  print self.__class__.__name__ ," die"

pyinput.Input.__del__ = deltalk
pygeom.ProbGeom1D.__del__ = deltalk
pystate.State1D.__del__ = deltalk
pyeqfactory.Equation1D.__del__ = deltalk
pyeigenprobfactory.EigenProb1D.__del__ = deltalk
pyeigensolver.EigenSolver1D.__del__ = deltalk
pypostprocessing.PostProcessing1D.__del__ = deltalk

inp = pyinput.Input("heter1d/1d1g_heter")
atexit.register(inp.__del__)

geo = pygeom.ProbGeom1D(inp)
atexit.register(geo.__del__)

state = pystate.State1D(inp, geo);
atexit.register(state.__del__)

equation = pyeqfactory.EqFactory1D.New(state)
atexit.register(equation.__del__)

eigenprob = pyeigenprobfactory.EigenProbFactory1D.New(state, equation)
atexit.register(eigenprob.__del__)

solver = pyeigensolver.EigenSolver1D(state, eigenprob)
atexit.register(solver.__del__)
```

and when I run the script I get

```
$ python test2_forest.py
EigenSolver1D  die
EigenProb1D  die
Equation1D  die
State1D  die
State1D  die
ProbGeom1D  die
Input  die
Goodbye!!

Input  die
EigenProb1D  die
State1D  die
ProbGeom1D  die
EigenSolver1D  die
Equation1D  die
```

### Nicer solution if you can directly modify the constructor

It would be much easier if I could just add the `atexit.register` in the constructor as in the following example

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import atexit

class Foo(object):
  def __init__(self, id):
    self.id = id
    atexit.register(self.__del__)
  def __del__(self):
    print(self.id, " says bye")

a = Foo(1)
b = Foo(2)
c = Foo(3)
```

But the classes are defined in c++ and parsed with SWIG, so I need to modify the constructor of an existing class definition to do it like this, so it is easier to do it manually for a short program.

### Modifying an existing constructor...

This is not the best option if you have to do it for many classes, but if you still want to avoid to register things manually. Having the class foo as follows

```
#simplefoo.py
class Foo(object):
  def __init__(self, id):
    self.id = id
```

the constructor of an existing class can be modified as follows

```
#test.py
from simplefoo import Foo

# first: I load the module atexit and register the bye function    
import atexit
def bye():
  print("Bye bye!")
atexit.register(bye)

# second: I add the destructor that talks loudly
def del_ini(self):
  print(self.id, " says bye")
Foo.__del__ = del_ini 

# third: I modify the original constructor. This is ugly
Foo.ini_old = Foo.__init__
def ini_new(self, id):
  self.ini_old(id)
  atexit.register(self.__del__)
Foo.__init__ = ini_new

# fourth: I create objects and finish the program them to see what happens

a = Foo(1)
b = Foo(2)
c = Foo(3)
```

And when we run the script we get

```
$ python3 test.py 
3  says bye
2  says bye
1  says bye
Bye bye!
3  says bye
1  says bye
2  says bye
```

Thanks.